# using constructor wit new object in Java

Tags: java, constructor, swap

```
public class swap
{
    public class Point
    {
        public int x=0;
        public int y=0;

        public Point(int a, int b)
        {
            this.x = a;
            this.y = b;
        }

        public void swapxy(Point p)
        {
            int t;

            t = p.x;
            p.x = p.y;
            p.y = t;
        }

        public String ToString()
        {
            return ("x="+x+" y="+y);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Point pxy = Point(10,20);

        pxy.swapxy(pxy);
        System.out.println(pxy);

    }

}
```

I am getting method is undefined error for `Point pxy = Point(10,20);` what is wrong ?

Comment: Please reformat your code. Copy it into an editor press TAB to indent it once and copy the code back into the question.

Comment: Do you have any C background?

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten the `new` keyword:

```
Point pxy = new Point(10,20);
            ↑↑↑
```

Comment: I added the "new" but stiil I am getting error: No enclosing instance of type swap is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type swap (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of swap).

Answer (score 3):

You forget to write the New after the "=";

The correct way is like that:

```
Point pxy = new Point(10,20);
```

Oh, the point is that the class you want to use is an innerClass of Swap, so you must instantiate it before you use it.

If you dont need this to be in an inner class, declare this class in a separated file, or you can do as the code bellow:

```
 public class Swap {
        //add static in the class to access it in a static way
         public static class Point
        {
//change the attributes to private, this is a good practice
            private int x=0;
            private int y=0;

            public Point(int a, int b)
            {
                this.x = a;
                this.y = b;
            }

            public void swapxy(Point p)
            {
                int t;

                t = p.x;
                p.x = p.y;
                p.y = t;
            }

            public String ToString()
            {
                return ("x="+x+" y="+y);
            }
        }

         public static void main(String[] args){

              Swap.Point pxy = new Swap.Point(10,20); 
              System.out.println(pxy.ToString());
         }

    }
```

Comment: I added the new but stiil I am getting error:  No enclosing instance of type swap is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type swap (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of swap).

Comment: I Edited the answer, give a look.

Answer (score 1):

The right way: `Point pxy = new Point(10,20);`

Answer (score 1):

To create an instance, use the 'new' keyword